# What's the internal command for entering a fraction?

Tags: front-end

I'm looking for the `` FrontEnd`Foo[...] ``-like command that's triggered when pressing `Ctrl + /`.

Are there any discoverability features in Mathematica that would have helped in this case?

E.g., in Emacs I could have just pressed `Ctrl + h k Ctrl + /` ("Find function for key `Ctrl + /`").

Comment: I don't know of any discoverability features, but there are docs http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FrontEndTokens.html and in particular http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/InsertTokens.html

Comment: @ens Please make sure that when you get enough rep you post it as a real answer instead of a comment! Nice and lucky first question, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 14):

With Michael's help (thanks) I figured out this snippet to do the job:

```
FrontEndExecute[{
    FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "Fraction"]
}]
```